# Unauthorized Access exception in OpenStreamForWriteAsync Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, jsonserializer, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I'm trying to save some informations into a file in the ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder this way:

```
private async Task WriteRecentScores(List<ScoreRecord> list)
    {
        try
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<ScoreRecord>));
            using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(
                          RECENTSCOREFILE,
                          CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(stream, list);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

but I get an Unauthorized Access exception when reaching OpenStreamForWriteAsync.

RECENTSCOREFILE="score.json" is a file created when launching the app for the very first time (I'm using the FailIfExists option), here's the code

```
private async void CreateFile()
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(RECENTSCOREFILE, CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        return;
    }
```

The funny thing is that I tried to launch the app both in the emulator and in my phone and it seems that it throws the exception only when running on the phone.

EDIT: I figured out that it works only the first time I *interact* with the file (create file is not needed as it seems), but how can I solve this?

Comment: Are you using somewhere else the file? - for example to read the score? Maybe the previous stream hasn't been disposed.

Comment: Yes i'm reading that same file from another page of my app, but i can't tell why it works in the emulator only

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is needed to localize the problem's origin. You could try to call await WriteRecentScores method several times consequentially (in the scope of same method). And I guess it will work fine. Then we could say that problem origin isn't in File modification logic itself.

The issue is definitely caused by someone uses that file in the same time. It could be caused by unintended calling of the 'Save' method several times simultaneously. For example quite often file modifications are made on HardwareButtons.BackPressed event, and if Unsubscribe on leaving the page not implemented, next time Back button will be pressed on the Page will lead your handler to be called twice at the same time.